# Converting a list of tuples to a deep nested list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, nested-lists

I have a program that generates the following list of tuples:

```
[('Government and politics', 2), ('Government', 3), ('Capital punishment', 4), ('Federal representation', 4), ('Politics', 3)]
```

Where the number reflects the hierarchy. I was wondering if there is a recursive way of converting this list of tuples into a nested list as follows:

```
['Government and politics', ['Government', ['Capital punishment', 'Federal representation'], 'Politics']]
```

Comment: Why not change the original program to generate what you need?

Comment: This is a part of a larger code that aims to replicate the headers (h1, h2 , ...) of Wikipedia articles. The current Wikipedia APIs provide a flat list of those headers. What I have here is as far as I could've pushed it to resemble a hierarchical structure.

Comment: Ok. Why do you want to use recursion? Have you tried a simple for loop?

Comment: When I do that, I run into trouble figuring out what criteria to use to stop the loop and how many times should I loop as every article does have a unique hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to use recursion in this case:

```
def nest(data, base=0):
    result = []
    for item, level in data:
        target = result
        for depth in range(base, level):
            if not (len(target) > 0 and isinstance(target[-1], list)):
                target.append([])
            target = target[-1]
        target.append(item)
    return result
```

The outer loop of this function iterates over the `item, level` pairs in your data, and the inner loop drills down to the appropriate depth, creating new sub-lists as necessary as it goes.

The `base` argument is the minimum level in your data, in this case `2`. Here it is in action:

```
>>> data = [
...     ('Government and politics', 2),
...     ('Government', 3),
...     ('Capital punishment', 4),
...     ('Federal representation', 4),
...     ('Politics', 3)
... ]
```

```
>>> nest(data, 2)
['Government and politics', ['Government', ['Capital punishment', 'Federal representation'], 'Politics']]
```